# How to check if a page component has a specified definePageMeta layout?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have made my application's page layout dynamic based on current user. But I want to check if the current page has explicitly defined its layout so that it will never be overridden by the `watchEffect` below.

(app.vue)

```js
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
    <ToastNotification></ToastNotification>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const globalStore = useGlobal();
const { user } = storeToRefs(globalStore);


onMounted(() => {
  watchEffect(() => {
    switch (user.value?.role) {
      case 'instructor':
        setPageLayout('instructor');
        break;
      case 'student':
        setPageLayout('student');
        break;
      default:
        setPageLayout('default');
        break;
    }
  });
})
</script>
```

(pages/someOtherPage.vue)

```js
<template>
  This should always be rendered in default layout.
</template>

<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'default',
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Was able to utilize `useRoute` for this.

```js
  watchEffect(() => {
    const route = useRoute()
    // `false` is a possible value also which is equivalent to 'default'.
    if (route.meta.layout || route.meta.layout === false) {
      // Do not override explicitly definded layouts.
      return;
    }

    switch (user.value?.role) {
      case 'instructor':
        setPageLayout('instructor');
        break;
      case 'student':
        setPageLayout('student');
        break;
      default:
        setPageLayout('default');
        break;
    }
  });
```

**NOTE** that `setPageLayout` also updatest the `meta.layout`. So you have to manage your dynamic layout logic carefully given the behavior.

(Leaving the post open for a while and not voting my answer to allow better alternative solutions.)